# Is it possible to wrap AVPlayer Play and Pause with AnyPublisher

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer, combine

I'm looking to wrap AVPlayer's play and pause methods so that I may use ReCombine effects to dispatch actions from SwiftUI which will ultimate play and pause some audio.

```
public extension AVPlayer {
    func timeControlPub() -> AnyPublisher<TimeControlStatus, Never> {
        publisher(for: \.timeControlStatus).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
    }
    
    func playPub() -> AnyPublisher<() -> Void, Never> {
        publisher(for: \.play).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

The above snippet shows the general idea of the playback API and errors with:

**Key path cannot refer to instance method 'play()'**

Ive also tried

```
protocol PlaybackAPIManager {
    func playStream() -> AnyPublisher<()-> Void, Never>
}

extension AVPlayer: PlaybackAPIManager {
    func playStream() -> AnyPublisher<()-> Void, Never>{
        return AVPlayer.play
    }
}
```

But receive the error:

**Cannot convert return expression of type '(AVPlayer) -> () -> Void' to return type 'AnyPublisher<() -> Void, Never>'**

```
static let togglePlayPause = Effect(dispatch: false)  { (actions: AnyPublisher<Action, Never>) in
            actions.ofTypes(TogglePlay.self)
                .flatMap(playStremAPI)
                .print("Stream Played")
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
```

I am have trouble wrapping AVPlayer methods with AnyPublisher to appease ReCombine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ReCombine, so it's not clear to me why you'd want a publisher that calls the `play` method. But here's one way to create a publisher that calls the `play` method each time you subscribe to it, then immediately ends the subscription with `.finished`.

```
import Combine
import AVFoundation

extension AVPlayer {
    func playPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Void, Never> {
        return Deferred {
            (self.play(), Empty()).1
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

I used `Deferred` so it doesn't call `play` until you subscribe, and calls `play` on each subscription.

I used the tuple `(self.play(), Empty()).1` so that the closure is a single expression, which lets Swift to deduce the generic parameter of the `Deferred`.

We could generalize the implementation to take a closure like this:

```
extension AnyPublisher where Output == Void, Failure == Never {
    static func call(_ body: @escaping () -> Void) -> Self {
        return Deferred {
            (body(), Empty()).1
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
let pub = AnyPublisher.call { player.play() }
```